# Obtaining the min and max of a two-dimensional array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would you obtain the min and max of a two-dimensional array using LINQ? And to be clear, I mean the min/max of the all items in the array (not the min/max of a particular dimension).

Or am I just going to have to loop through the old fashioned way?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since Array implements `IEnumerable` you can just do this:

```
var arr = new int[2, 2] {{1,2}, {3, 4}};
int max = arr.Cast<int>().Max();    //or Min
```

Comment: For future searchers, http://stackoverflow.com/a/641565 for Jagged Arrays ie. `int[][] SomeArray = ...;`, use `var Flattened = SomeArray.SelectMany(x => x)` which aggregates the enumerators. Then you can just do `Flattened.Max()` for example.

Comment: Josh: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the way this looks to me, you would copy the entire array into another flattened array just to do a maximum search, which incurs firstly the copying overhead, and then another O(n) and hence has terrible overall complexity for such a simple problem. Sometimes elegance and brevity really isn't everything.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work:

```
IEnumerable<int> allValues = myArray.Cast<int>();
int min = allValues.Min();
int max = allValues.Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

here is variant:

```
var maxarr = (from int v in aarray select v).Max();
```

where aarray is int[,]

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `List<List<type>>` and find the min and max in a `foreach` loop, and store it to a `List`. Then you can easily find the `Min()` and `Max()` from that list of all the values in a single-dimensional list.

That is the first thing that comes to mind, I am curious of this myself and am gonna see if google can grab a more clean cut approach.

Comment: How would you even get a two-dimensional array into a list in the first place?

Comment: Ah, I thought to far ahead, now I realize if you were to get the array into a list, you could use the code to get the MIN/MAX out of the same loop i envisioned to populate the Lists.

:/ tis been a long mourning with not enough coffee :D

Comment: You can flatten the array, @devuxer