# How to use LINQ on a multidimensional array to 'unwind' the array?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

Consider the following array:

`int[,] numbers = new int[3, 2] { { 2, 1 }, { 3, 4 }, { 6, 5 } };`

I would like to use LINQ to construct an IEnumerable with numbers 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5.

What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: That's a 2d array not an array of arrays(jagged array).

Comment: You're right... it's a multidimensional array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert 2 dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641499/convert-2-dimensional-array)

Comment: There is a linq query in the duplicate, but i would go with a foreach as the linq query is quite opaque and the foreach is clear what you are doing.

Comment: @BenRobinson, I need to use LINQ, the other problem does not use LINQ.

Comment: 'var flatNumbers = numbers.Cast<int>();' copied and modified from the linked post.  All LINQ

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker I rolled back your last edits, because that was radical change of your initial question

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, just added a second post with the LINQ question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
Enumerable
    .Range(0,numbers.GetUpperBound(0)+1)
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(0,numbers.GetUpperBound(1)+1)
    .Select (y =>numbers[x,y] ));
```

or to neaten up.

```
var xLimit=Enumerable.Range(0,numbers.GetUpperBound(0)+1);
var yLimit=Enumerable.Range(0,numbers.GetUpperBound(1)+1);
var result = xLimit.SelectMany(x=> yLimit.Select(y => numbers[x,y]));
```

EDIT Revised Question....

```
var result = array.SelectMany(x => x.C);
```

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps simply:

```
var all = numbers.Cast<int>();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/yoXQZD)

Comment: +1 from me - `Cast` is a has a little less overhead then `OfType` in this case

Comment: Upvoted. But in either way we get _boxing_ and _unboxing_ because this goes through the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface which yields `object` boxes which are the unboxed by `Cast`.

Answer (score 6):

Use simple foreach to get your numbers from 2d array:

```
int[,] numbers = new int[3, 2] { { 2, 1 }, { 3, 4 }, { 6, 5 } };
foreach(int x in numbers)
{
   // 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5.
}
```

LINQ (it's an big overhead to use Linq for your initial task, because instead of simple iterating array, CastIterator (Tim's answer) of OfTypeIterator will be created)

```
IEnumerable<int> query = numbers.OfType<int>();
```

Comment: I need to use LINQ. My problem is a tat more complex... but I need to use LINQ. Each object in the array has a property that has an array that I'll need to mash into a single list.

Comment: Please post your whole problem as you will get different answers

Comment: It may be homework, but it may also be the smallest working example of a mind-bogglingly complex system, which the asker didn't want to bother us with ;-)