# How to use LINQ to get a single IENumerable<X> from a property of an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Consider the following array:

```
class B { }

class A 
{
    IEnumerable<B> C { get; }
}

IEnumerable<A> array;
```

I need to end up with one `IEnumerable<B>`. I'm ending up with `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<B>>`:

`var q = array.Select(a => a.C);`

How can I unwind the array?

Comment: You didn't show us the code you're using to get `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<B>>`.  It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by unwind? Do you mean transforming a two dimensional array into a single dimensional array?

Comment: @RyanGates, I rephrased the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<B> allBs = array.SelectMany(a => a.C);
```

Comment: Crystal ball analysis at its finest.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not really, I was just privy to the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822750/how-to-use-linq-on-a-multidimensional-array-to-unwind-the-array) where OP generalized this in a way that didn't really generalize, then edited his question to degeneralize it, then had his edit rolled back because people had answered the original.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
var q = array.SelectMany(a => a.C);
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<B>` containing the flattened contents of the `C` property of each item in `array`.