# LINQ .Any() iterator for 2D Array - [,]

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

What is the proper way to handle a **2D array** with **LINQ**?

```
int[,] array =
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};

bool anyZeroes = array.Any(value => value == 0)     // example
```

I want to check if any variable in the array matches a `Func`, `== 0` in this case. How can I use `Any` for this and what is the best practice here?

Comment: Does that code compile or is it supposed to indicate your intent?

Comment: It's how I would want it to write.

Comment: Alright. I'm pretty sure it doesn't work because the vector style array you got there (2D, whatever you want to call it) doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, meaning it's not possible.

Comment: Yep... The question it duplicates explains. Personally I just avoid using `[ , ]` type of arrays altogether. I've never seen an example where they're more appropriate or useful than a `List<T[]>` or an array of arrays.

Comment: When you have a fixed size "grid", like in a 2D board game, what else should you use? A `List` misleadingly suggest that items can be added, which will caused undefined behavior.

Comment: That is actually one good application of it. But, that being said, every game written in C++ and C had no problem using plain old arrays. You could always implement a `Board` class that wraps something like a `List<int[]>`. Personally I would not use the 2D vector at the cost of using LINQ but in this case I could at least understand the decision to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can flatten the list to check

```
bool anyZeroes = array.Cast<int>().Any(value => value == 0);// false
bool anyNines = array.Cast<int>().Any(value => value == 9);// true
```

Though, if you are making multiple calls you should store it:

```
bool casted = array.Cast<int>();
bool anyZeroes = casted.Any(value => value == 0);// false
bool anyNines = casted.Any(value => value == 9);// true
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13822900/526704

Comment: Wow, so simple! Why didn't I think of this myself? Thanks :D

Comment: it's a bit counter-intuitive to me that a multi-dimm array would be able to be so easily "flattened". I had originally thought of it more as a `List<List<T>>` and tried to do a `SelectMany()` on it, but that doesn't work. I guess `Cast<T>()` just turns it into an `IEnumerable` which LINQ can handle better