# Find all bytes in multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have a 2D array of bytes ranging from 0 to 4 which are all jumbled up. What I want to do is specify a byte value, for example, 3. Then I want to get the offset (x and y location) of every 3 in the array and put them in a list (or another array) so I can iterate through all the 3s.

I'm pretty sure this is possible, I just don't know how to do it. I'm aware that there is no prebuilt method for iterating through multidimensional arrays so I'll have to write a method to do that.

To summarise: Filter all bytes of a certain type from a 2D array and put their coordinates (offsets) in a list or another array.

Comment: _so I'll have to write a method to do that_, so do that! Show us what you have tried so far, and if you have a specific question, we will be happy to help you :)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: start by using a jagged array, its just better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641499/convert-2-dimensional-array

Comment: What does your method for iterating through the multidimensional array look like? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks for all the fast answers, Eminem, I'm trying to write one but I'm just really confused about my own code :P. Jodrell, Why is a jagged array better? Martijn, all my code is at https://github.com/Pyroglyph/PlasmaticRevolution, Tile.cs and Map.cs are the main ones that relate to this question.

Comment: Okay so I added Diogo's code from the answer below but now it compiles fine but does nothing. It doesn't even draw the CornflowerBlue background that normally comes up in XNA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Vector2
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}


 public List<Vector2> GetBytes(byte[,] array, byte value)
    {
        List<Vector2> list = new List<Vector2>();
        int count;
        for (int i = 0; i < XSize; i++)
            for (int k = 0; k < YSize; k++)
                if (array[i, k] == value)
                    list.Add(new Vector2 { X = i, Y = k });
        return list;
    }
```

This should do it.

Edited, you can see the values like:

```
list[position].X
list[position].Y
```

Comment: Nice, I never thought of using a Vector2.

Comment: If you want to iterate trought all members of the list you can do a foreach like
foreach(Vector2 v in list)
print(v.X + ' ' + v.Y);